# Negation of the statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to negate the following expression to obtain the formula that does not contain $\neg$ , $\land$ and $\lor$:
$(\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y)) \land (\exists x) (\forall y) (\neg R(x,y) \land Q(x,y))$

I attempted the question the following way but I am not sure if my solution is correct since there is a lot of back and forth going on:

So I need to find

$\neg [(\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y)) \land (\exists x) (\forall y) (\neg R(x,y) \land Q(x,y))]$ $= [\neg (\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y)\land Q(x,y)] \lor [\neg (\exists x) (\forall y) (\neg R(x,y) \land Q(x,y))]$ $= [(\exists x) (\forall y) \neg (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))] \lor (\forall x) (\exists y) \neg(\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))]$ $= \neg[(\exists x) (\forall y) \neg (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))] \implies [(\forall x) (\exists y) \neg(\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))]$ $= [(\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y)] \implies [(\forall x) (\exists y)(P(x,y) \land \neg Q(x,y))]$ $= [(\forall x) (\exists y) \neg(\neg P(x,y) \implies \neg Q(x,y))] \implies [(\forall x) (\exists y) \neg ((P(x,y) \implies Q(x,y))]$ $= [(\exists x) (\forall y) (Q(x,y) \implies P(x,y))] \implies [(\exists x) (\forall y) ((P(x,y) \implies Q(x,y))]$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am very confused as to how $R$ just goes away from Step 2 to Step 3.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: The $R$ lifted up one leg.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

> $\neg A \equiv A \to \bot$.
>
> $\neg A \lor B \equiv A \to B$.
>
> $\neg A \land B \equiv \neg( \neg B \lor A ) \equiv \neg( B \to A ) \equiv ( B \to A ) \to \bot$.
>
> $A \lor B \equiv \neg A \to B \equiv ( A \to \bot ) \to B$.

We cannot rewrite "$\bot$" using only propositional variables and "$\to$", because any proposition would be of the form "$A \to B$", which we can make true by making $B$ true recursively.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please explain what does "⊥" mean?

Comment: @Blondie: It stands for a contradiction (always false), also called "falsum". My last sentence therefore means that no propositional formula using only implication is always false, and hence having implication is not sufficient to express all possible propositional formulae.

Answer (score 0):

From Step 2 to Step 3, you make a typo and replace $R$ with $P$, which is easily fixed.

However, from Step 4 to Step 5, you seem to apply De Morgan's Law incorrectly and say $\neg(\neg R(x, y) \wedge Q(x, y)) \iff R(x, y) \wedge \neg Q(x, y)$ even though it should $R(x, y) \vee \neg Q(x, y)$. I will continue from there:
$$[(\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))] \implies [(\forall x) (\exists y)(R(x,y) \vee \neg Q(x,y))]$$
Use material implication to change $R(x,y) \vee \neg Q(x,y)$ into $Q(x,y) \implies R(x,y)$:
$$[(\forall x) (\exists y) (\neg P(x,y) \land Q(x,y))] \implies [(\forall x) (\exists y)(Q(x,y) \implies R(x,y))]$$
At this point, I am also stuck, so hopefully someone else can continue from here.

Comment: Oh right, thank you! As for the left component of the expression that is [(∀x)(∃y)(¬P(x,y)∧Q(x,y))] I think it is equal to [(∀x)(∃y)¬(¬P(x,y)⟹¬Q(x,y))] = [(∃x)(∀y)(Q(x,y)⟹P(x,y))]. Please correct if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Blondie Correct!

Comment: @Blondie I do not think this is correct. You are saying $(\forall x)(\exists y)\neg F(x, y)$ is the same as $(\exists x)(\forall y)F(x, y)$ where $F(x, y)=\neg P(x, y) \implies \neg Q(x, y)$, which is the same as $F(x, y)=Q(x, y) \implies P(x, y)$ by contrapositives. However, this is not true. These two statements are negations of each other, not logically equivalent.

Comment: @Blondie: See my answer for how to get rid of negation.